# How do I best communicate a (chat) status of "application installed on phone"?

Tags: mobile, status

I'm looking to communicate, to a chat user, that their chat partner is available in the meaning of "has installed a chat application on their smartphone".

Marking the chat partner as "online" or "available" doesn't seem quite right - since they might be busy at the moment. Marking them as "offline" or "unavailable" is also not quite right - since they most likely will respond to messages, though probably with some delay.

Any thoughts? I know facebook uses a phone icon to mark this status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're "**Mobile**".

It's as simple as that, it denotes their current "Maybe I'm here, maybe I'm not, but I am online" state. When IMs don't have this state it's common for people to think you're just plain online, which can result in people IMing you thinking you're *right there*, so make sure you *do* communicate this.

If you have icons, a phone icon is a great way to denote this as you mentioned. AIM does this as you can see in this sample screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A common trend for marking a user status appears to be color centric. Facebook, Microsoft Lync and many other clients use green to show that a user is available/actively online. Other colors like yellow/orange are being used to indicate that the user is Busy/Away but still online. Red seems to be common method to indicate that a use is online but unable is currently unavailable or does not want to be disturbed.  Lastly if a chat client shows when a user is offline the common color is a gray icon or username being grayed out as if it is disabled. Image below from Microsoft Lync

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I know facebook uses a phone icon to mark this status.

So how about using a phone icon to mark that status? :) It sounds like a very effective solution, and this way you don't need to look for the most appropriate term for this.